# Reading influxdb result into string results in error: interface{} is json.Number, not string

Tags: go, influxdb

I'm trying to convert an influxdb `record` (type: `[]interface{}`) to `[]string` so I can write it to csv.

#### Record

> [2018-12-20T07:26:23Z 90 123.2132 12.3232 30 1 user]

#### Code

```golang
s := make([]string, len(record))
for i, v := range record {
    s[i] = v.(string)
}
```

But I got this error

> interface {} is json.Number, not string

I'm new to golang and not too familiar with interface and json

Comment: Can you show us the raw JSON that you're dealing with?

Comment: @KoalaYeung it's this [2018-12-20T07:26:23Z 90 123.2132 12.3232 30 1 user]. I retrieved the data from influxdb. I supposed each of them have their own json.type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your record array is generated somewhat like this by your database driver:

```golang
record := make([]interface{}, 0, 10)
dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(`["2018-12-20T07:26:23Z", 90, 123.2132, 12.3232, 30, 1, "user"]`))
dec.UseNumber()
dec.Decode(&record)
```

All numbers are generated as `json.Number` instead `float64`. Since `json.Number` support a simple conversion to string, you may use that interface along with a simple [type switch](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16) to do this:

```golang
s := make([]string, len(record))
for i, v := range record {
    switch val := v.(type) {
    case string:
        s[i] = val
    case json.Number:
        s[i] = val.String()
    default:
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("unhandled type: %T", v))
    }
}
```

See this in action:
https://play.golang.org/p/jD_z94vQ7Wt

Comment: @Charles: Nice :-)